# IS it OK to use a class for connecting to my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a public class called `dbOPS` that has some subs and functions like:

```
 Public Function getSqlReader(ByVal sql As String) As SqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, getConn)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 360
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    Return dr
End Function

Public Function getSqlScalar(ByVal sql As String)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, getConn)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 360
    Dim cnt = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    closeCX()
    Return cnt
End Function

Public Sub ExecuteSql(ByVal sql As String)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, getConn)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 360
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    closeCX()
End Sub
```

I then use the following command once per page and use the db variable many (many) times throughout the page:

```
Dim db as new dbOPS
```

Recently, I have started getting many errors

> ExecuteScalar requires an open and available connection. the connection's current state is connecting

Is this the cause?

Is there any way around it without rewriting every page and every command to open its own connection?

Thanks

Comment: Depends, but don't forget to you use usings don't know the key word in VB.NET in order to dispose disposable objects you create! 
Ipmlement a function the gives you a new and opened SQLConnection, do CRUD's and dispose the connection as soon as possible

Comment: I have close and dispose set on on all my readers

Comment: Do they close in case of error?

Comment: Don't think so.  That might be something to look at. But I don't have that many errors.

Comment: @Legends - it's the same keyword in VB.NET - `Using` as it is in C# - `using`, OP will just have to mark the end of the block with `End Using`.

Comment: What's getConn doing? I guess it should be providing an open SqlConnection object. I suspect this is probably where your problem is. Also, you can create the SqlCommand  and set it's timeout in a getCmd function instead of writing it 3 times.

Comment: A DAL (data access layer) should return data, *not* components related to the inner workings of the DAL itself. You need to keep those sql objects as local as possible. ExecuteAdapter/Reader should return a data set/table or a list of business objects (entities). ExecuteScalar should return the scalar result. And ExecuteNonQuery should return the number of affected rows. You'll find a simple example of a DAL class over at code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/85506/36214

Comment: Turn Option strict on...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to detect the connection and reopen them just in case it is not open prior to executing the command.

```
If (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) Then
    cmd.Connection.Open()
```

Do this as part of your helper methods.